# Downloading Ganache Truffle Suite from their website and installing on windows gives error

Tags: ganache

When you download Ganache Truffle Suite from their website: https://trufflesuite.com/ganache/
for windows and install it, it gives an error:

`App installation failed with error message: error -2018574325: Windows cannot process a deployment operation because the package repository database encountered an unrecoverable error. Use the Reset Your PC feature to recover your PC. (0x80004005)`

Answer (score 5):

If you are downloading Ganache Truffle Suite from their website it will be a .appx file and when you try to install it on windows Os it will give an error. So you should get the .exe file from Github and install it. You can visit this link for the same: https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-ui/releases/download/v2.5.4/Ganache-2.5.4-win-setup.exe