# App installation failed with error message: error 0x80070005 while installing ganache

Tags: windows, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, ganache

I'm trying to install ganache from the launcher in my new pc but windows just won't leave me.

I already tried a lot of things but nothing appears to work, it's always the same message:

**App installation failed with error message: error 0x80070005: error al abrir el paquete desde la ubicación Ganache-2.5.4-win-x64.appx. (0x80070005)**[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution
In another post, the user **Ajit Chaudhary** answered a similar problem so I will copy&paste what he said. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70634946/18707882)

"If you are downloading Ganache Truffle Suite from their website it will be a .appx file and when you try to install it on windows Os it will give an error. So you should get the .exe file from Github and install it. You can visit this link for the same: [https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-ui/releases/download/v2.5.4/Ganache-2.5.4-win-setup.exe"](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-ui/releases/download/v2.5.4/Ganache-2.5.4-win-setup.exe%22)